# Same Image and Shapefile are not overlapping in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, digitizing, jpg, arcview-3

An image is Digitized in ArcView 3.3 with JPEG extension; But not with Image analysis extension.

When I open that image and shapefile in ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop then they are not overlaping each other ... why is that?

How can I overlap the image and shapefile?

Comment: You have a georeferenced jpg and a shapefile which was digitized from it? When you say "not overlapping", by how much? Are they close or in entirely different places.

Comment: jpg is not a spatially aware format. For it to be correctly displayed relative to a shapefile, it would need an accompanying world file - do you have that, or just the jpg?

Comment: the image is not geo-referenced yet. The Image is digitize only in Arc view 3.3 version with jpeg extension only.........but  when the Image analysis extension active then the image and shape file not overlap..........its overlap only in jpeg extension.@ Neil

Comment: just the jpeg@ Chris

Answer (score 1):

JPEG isn't a spatially aware format. That means it doesn't have the ability to store georeferencing information internally, like a geotiff or potentially the newer JPEG2000 format. If you do not have an accompanying world file, there is no way for Arc to know where the image is supposed to be on the surface of the earth. It sounds like at some point in the past the image *was* georeferenced (or perhaps you're referring to a jpg of the shapefile that was exported), and that information was stored somewhere else or the world file lost.

Your only option if you cannot locate some external file with the georeferencing information is to re-reference it using the shapefile to match points to. See the [help files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_georeferencing_a_raster_dataset/009t000000mn000000/) on georeferencing.

Comment: @Tarek Happy to help. Please consider [clicking the check mark to accept the answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if it has answered your question. With a bit more rep you'll also be able to upvote answers you find useful or helpful.